# Retrieve Username instead of ObjectID in Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, parse-platform

Using angular and Parse for JavaScript, I have a search field when an admin types the objectid of the user, upon clicking submit the details of the user are populated in their respective field. My problem is that instead of using the objectid as a reference point, I would like to use the username. Where instead of typing out the objectid, he would enter the username instead, and their respective information would be populated.

Below is how I display user information based on the objectid provided (want to change that to username).
Script

```
//To search and display user information
   $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
       $scope.loading = true;

   // now access $scope.userId here
   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

   query.get($scope.userId, {
       success: function(userInfo) {
           // The object was retrieved successfully.
           var address = userInfo.get("address");
           $scope.address = address;

           var email = userInfo.get("username");
           $scope.email = email;

            var fullName = userInfo.get("fullName");
           $scope.fullName=  fullName;

               var number = userInfo.get("phoneNumber");
           $scope.number=  number;

            var mailingAddress = userInfo.get("mailingAddress");
           $scope.mailingAddress =  mailingAddress;

               var plan = userInfo.get("plan");
           $scope.plan =  plan;


                var phone = userInfo.get("Phone");
           $scope.phone = 'Phone: ' + phone;

             var scanURL = '<a href="scan.html">Scan</a>';
           $scope.scanURL = scanURL;
                      $scope.loading = false;


       },
       error: function(object, error) {
           // The object was not retrieved successfully.
           // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                      $scope.loading = false;

       }
   });
```

html

```
<form>
<label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search username to begin" class="btn btn-danger" id="searchBar" ng-model="userId"></input>
</label>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="searchButton" ng-click="userIdChanged()">SEARCH</button> </form>
    <h4 id="messageSent"></h4> 
<form>
```

**Update:**

```
//To search and display user information
   $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
       $scope.loading = true;

       // now access $scope.userId here
       var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

       query.equalTo("username", $scope.userId); 


       query.find({ success: function(userInfo) {
               // The object was retrieved successfully.
               var address = userInfo.get("address");
               $scope.address = address;

               var email = userInfo.get("username");
               $scope.email = email;

                var fullName = userInfo.get("fullName");
               $scope.fullName=  fullName;

                   var number = userInfo.get("phoneNumber");
               $scope.number=  number;

                var mailingAddress = userInfo.get("mailingAddress");
               $scope.mailingAddress =  mailingAddress;

                   var plan = userInfo.get("plan");
               $scope.plan =  plan;


                    var phone = userInfo.get("Phone");
               $scope.phone = 'Phone: ' + phone;

                 var scanURL = '<a href="scan.html">Scan</a>';
               $scope.scanURL = scanURL;
                          $scope.loading = false;


           },
           error: function(object, error) {
               // The object was not retrieved successfully.
               // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                          $scope.loading = false;

           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out th the parse.com docs on queries.  In the meantime, queries can be given constraints with methods like `equalTo`:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", $scope.userId); 
// assuming that you're putting the username input text into $scope.userId
query.find({ success: function(array) {

           // this means the query was a success, but we're not yet certain that we found anything
           // the param to find's success is an array of PFObjects, possibly empty

           if (array.length > 0) {
               var userInfo = array[0];
               var address = userInfo.get("address");
               $scope.address = address;

               var email = userInfo.get("username");
               $scope.email = email;
               // you original code here ...

           } else {
               // the query is a success with no results,
               // which means  that no records match the criteria you gave
               alert("nothing found");
           }

       },
       error: function(object, error) {
           // The object was not retrieved successfully.
           // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                      $scope.loading = false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will dive into the parse doc. I have applied your suggestion, for some reason it doesnt seem to be responding anymore, where before I would type the objectid, and its respective fields would get populated, but now as i type the username, nothing happens. I have included under the update section of my initial post the revision (where when a user types the username, it pulls respective data about that user)

Comment: Find returns an array, so your code should check for a > 0 length then choose one or all of the objects to present in the UI.